# Is there any ready Amazon MWS solution to put ASIN, Address, Box weight and get shipping label?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-fba

I'm a Amazon seller and sell dozens of different products.

Everyday I'm doing the same job: choose ASIN, send/replenish inventory, choose address, packing-type, quantity, box weight and dimensions, get UPS shipping label.

Trying to find some service to automate this process or maybe there is some ready script that I can give to my php developer and he could create this product.

By the way, I know about docs.mws .com and manuals (from 2009-2011).

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

We were doing that manually at first, but a couple years ago, I created an application that uses the [Fulfillment Inbound Shipment API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/index.html).  We pick the ASIN's, input weight/dimensions, get guidance, create shipping plans, shipments, download .pdf labels, everything from the API.  There is a [PHP client SDK](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/139-9943795-1024558?ie=UTF8&group=fulfillment&section=inbound&version=latest) that can help your developer get started very quickly.

Comment: The question was that I'm looking for that application. And my last phrase was that I know about SDK.

Comment: Well I gave you right where the scripts are.  I don’t know of an app but I’m sure they exist. You can download the php kit and have an app in 5 mins.  Just trying to help.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not programmer) also it's quite hard to explain to my coder logic part of this idea because he never ever saw amazon seller account :D thats why I'm looking for the ready one...